# Error building/installing mod_wsgi on AWS elasticbeanstalk for Django deployment

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I'm getting the following error trying to deploy a Django app. I've been following the tutorial in the documentation at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html. My current hunch is it's because pip is trying to build mod_wsgi from source instead of using a .whl, but that's the extent of my troubleshooting expertise. How can I fix it?

```
[2015-11-20T02:11:22.515Z] INFO  [23704] - [Application update/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] : Activity execution failed, because: Collecting Django==1.8.6 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
    Using cached Django-1.8.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting mod-wsgi==4.4.7 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
    Using cached mod_wsgi-4.4.7.tar.gz
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-EAwCnb/mod-wsgi/setup.py", line 140, in <module>
          'missing Apache httpd server packages.' % APXS)
      RuntimeError: The 'apxs' command appears not to be installed or is not executable. Please check the list of prerequisites in the documentation for this package and install any missing Apache httpd server packages.

      ----------------------------------------
  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-EAwCnb/mod-wsgi
  2015-11-20 02:11:22,510 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: Collecting Django==1.8.6 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
    Using cached Django-1.8.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting mod-wsgi==4.4.7 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
    Using cached mod_wsgi-4.4.7.tar.gz
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-EAwCnb/mod-wsgi/setup.py", line 140, in <module>
          'missing Apache httpd server packages.' % APXS)
      RuntimeError: The 'apxs' command appears not to be installed or is not executable. Please check the list of prerequisites in the documentation for this package and install any missing Apache httpd server packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorted it.

apsx is supplied by the httpd-devel package. Use eb ssh to connect then

```
yum list installed|grep httpd
```

to see what version of httpd-devel matches the environment. Install with

```
sudo yum install httpd24-devel
```

and then

```
sudo /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt
```

to check that it's fixed.  If that works then create or edit a (local) file

```
.ebextensions/01_packages.config
```

or similar to add that as part of the deployment:

```
packages:
    yum:
        httpd24-devel: []
```